# What does export=typeof import() mean?

Tags: typescript, typescript-declarations

Consider the following code (seen [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30471#issuecomment-474963436)):

```
declare module "foobar" {
  export = typeof import("foobar")
}
```

What exactly does the second line do?
Doesn't it recursively refer to the same module?
Also, why is  a type *annotation* accepted as an exported value?

Answer (score 2):

The `typeof` operator in TS resolves the type of a given variable.  Imports return variables.  So what this is doing is exporting *the type* of `import('foo')` rather than the *value* of `import('foo')`.

Comment: But aren't `export`s supposed to be expressions? Whereas `typeof import(...)` is a type annotation

Comment: @ᆼᆺᆼ you can have type expressions in TS (just like `typeof import(...)`. They can be used for annotating types, but you can also have whole statements like defining a type variable (`type FoobarImport = typeof import('foobar'); export { FoobarImport }` that deal only with types. AFAIK if you only import types from a certain module, no code will be generated to actually import that module at runtime.

Comment: Ok so the type of the module `"foobar"` at runtime will be? `undefined`?

Comment: There won't be any ts type at runtime. Places where you would be using "foobar" be the places where you dealing with types, not values